# How do I determine when a table is going to span multiple pages with iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I am building a table that spans multiple pages of my PDF. I would like the column header of the table to appear as the first row on each page. Is there some way that I can detect when the page is breaking and insert the column headers rather than the next data row?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've worked directly in iText, but I believe there was a function that toggled you into a "practice" writing mode - you could execute write functions and get the returned dimensions, but it wouldn't actually affect the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the iTextSharp tutorial on SourceForge, [chapter 5](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch05.html), section "Large Tables," [example 10](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/examples/Chap0510.cs).

You basically call `EndHeaders()` on your `Table`.

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure how I missed that in the docs. I guess I fail at RTFM :)

Comment: Easy to miss considering the state of the documentation!

Comment: These links are broken.